# strdup invalid read of size 4 when string literal is ending with newline \n

Tags: c, strdup

I am getting an invalid read error when the src string ends with `\n`, the error disappear when i remove `\n`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char *txt = strdup ("this is a not socket terminated message\n");
    printf ("%d: %s\n", strlen (txt), txt);
    free (txt);
    return 0;
}
```

valgrind output:

```
==18929== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18929==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18929==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 84 bytes allocated
==18929== 
==18929== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==18929== 
==18929== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==18929== 
==18929== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==18929== Invalid read of size 4
==18929==    at 0x804847E: main (in /tmp/test)
==18929==  Address 0x4204050 is 40 bytes inside a block of size 41 alloc'd
==18929==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==18929==    by 0x8048415: main (in /tmp/test)
==18929== 
==18929== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

How to fix this without sacrificing the new line character?

Comment: Make certain `strdup()` is prototyped.  Use `"%zu"` for `strlen()`.  `'\n'` is not likely the issue.

Comment: No prob on MSVC with the proper header files. Where are they?

Comment: on MSVC everything is possible, this is not proper reference when it comes to C

Comment: The problem is most likely the format specifier.  Use %lu and not %d.  Turn on -Wformat if you're using gcc.

Comment: @tinky_winky are you trying to say that a decent compiler will work *without* the proper header files?

Comment: @chux I'm using ISO C90, is there an alternative format flag?

Comment: `printf ("%u: %s\n", (unsigned)strlen (txt), txt);`

Comment: @WeatherVane this should be %zu, not %u

Comment: @tinky_winky I know, but if you read carefully OP has (just above) asked how to do it without `%zu` and has repeated that below your answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane right, then %llu will be handy. Thank you.

Comment: @razzak With C90, cast result to widest available unsigned type which is at least `unsigned long`: `printf ("%lu\n", (unsigned long) strlen(txt));`

Comment: @chux `printf ("%lu\n", (unsigned long) strlen(txt));` is giving the same error! is there something wrong with my platform? i'm using ubuntu 32 bits

Comment: You code snippet lacks `include` files - why are they not included in your post? AFAIK, `strdup()` is not prototyped nor implemented correctly.  It is not a standard function.  Are all your warnings enabled at compile time?

Comment: I don't think that you are sharing us the right code here, because you have this `total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 84 bytes allocated` there are 2 allocs, why ?

Comment: You are just messing things here. You shouldn't post code which does nothing to do with the Output you show.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not about the newline character, nor the printf format specifier.  You've found what is arguably a bug in `strlen()`, and I can tell you must be using gcc.

Your program code is perfectly fine.  The printf format specifier could be a little better, but it won't cause the valgrind error you are seeing.  Let's look at that valgrind error:

```
==18929== Invalid read of size 4
==18929==    at 0x804847E: main (in /tmp/test)
==18929==  Address 0x4204050 is 40 bytes inside a block of size 41 alloc'd
==18929==    at 0x402A17C: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==18929==    by 0x8048415: main (in /tmp/test)
```

"Invalid read of size 4" is the first message we must understand.  It means that the processor ran an instruction which would load 4 consecutive bytes from memory.  The next line indicates that the address attempted to be read was "Address 0x4204050 is 40 bytes inside a block of size 41 alloc'd."

With this information, we can figure it out.  First, if you replace that `'\n'` with a `'$'`, or any other character, the same error will be produced.  Try it.

Secondly, we can see that your string has 40 characters in it.  Adding the `\0` termination character brings the total bytes used to represent the string to 41.

Because we have the message "Address 0x4204050 is 40 bytes inside a block of size 41 alloc'd," we now know everything about what is going wrong.

1. `strdup()` allocated the correct amount of memory, 41 bytes.
2. `strlen()` attempted to read 4 bytes, starting at the 40th, which would extend to a non-existent 43rd byte.
3. valgrind caught the problem

This is a glib() bug.  Once upon a time, a project called Tiny C Compiler (TCC) was starting to take off.  Coincidentally, glib was completely changed so that the normal string functions, such as `strlen()` no longer existed.  They were replaced with optimized versions which read memory using various methods such as reading four bytes at a time.  gcc was changed at the same time to generate calls to the appropriate implementations, depending on the alignment of the input pointer, the hardware compiled for, etc.  The TCC project was abandoned when this change to the GNU environment made it so difficult to produce a new C compiler, by taking away the ability to use glib for the standard library.

If you report the bug, glib maintainers probably won't fix it.  The reason is that under practical use, this will likely never cause an actual crash.  The `strlen` function is reading bytes 4 at a time because it sees that the addresses are 4-byte aligned.  It's always possible to read 4 bytes from a 4-byte-aligned address without segfaulting, given that reading 1 byte from that address would succeed.  Therefore, the warning from valgrind doesn't reveal a potential crash, just a mismatch in assumptions about how to program.  I consider valgrind technically correct, but I think there is zero chance that glib maintainers will do anything to squelch the warning.

Comment: I can confirm that replacing `\n` with any other caracters produce the same error, i'm also using gcc. Thanks for the lengthy explanation it all makes sense now.

Comment: Nice answer but the Output he gave has nothing to do with the code. In the Output he showed us this `total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 84 bytes allocated`. Where does `alloc` happens two times ?

Comment: @Michi - probably inside of `printf`.

Comment: @Michi probably in the glib start-up code: crt0.c.  Anyway, not a big deal.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt Is there an option in valgrind to silence these errors? i'm getting plenty of them with strlen.

Comment: @razzak - It looks here ( https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=678518 ) as if there is no valgrind workaround, but that compiling with ```-fno-builtin-strlen``` will generate code that is slower, but does not trigger this warning.

Comment: @HeathHunnicutt Brilliant, `-fno-builtin-strlen` worked great, now i can focus on the real errors :)

Answer (score 3):

The error message seems to indicate that it's `strlen` that read past the `malloc`ed buffer allocated by `strdup`. On a 32-bit platform, an optimal `strlen` implementation could read 4 bytes at a time into a 32-bit register and do some bit-twiddling to see if there's a null byte in there. If near the end of the string, there are less than 4 bytes left, but 4 bytes are still read to perform the null byte check, then I could see this error getting printed. In that case, presumably the `strlen` implementer would know if it's "safe" to do this on the particular platform, in which case the valgrind error is a false positive.